# OpenSSL libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll missing

Tags: c++, openssl, g++, runtime-error, system-error

i have started a project in C++ and need to implement some openssl libraries. I downloaded the libraries, followed the directions on how to install openssl.

it was a pain and had to install / reinstall multiple times for multiple reasons.

im finally able to seemingly correctly install openssl and compile the libraries, link them with -libcrypto and -libssl instead of the -lcrypto and -lssl i saw everywhere.

I have been through the process of debugging, my includes are fine and the implimentation seems to work because g++ find the error file and throws the compilation errors, but when it "Succesfully" compiles and i run the .exe i get this error.

[image]

**I have searched my openssl intall location and i did find that file.**

[image]

**Here is my makefile code, all those location are clearly in the building path**

```
# *- Makefile -*

compiler=g++
standLib=-lstdc++ -llibcrypto -llibssl
include=-I C:\openssl-1.1.0e\include 
ExtLibrary=-L C:\openssl-1.1.0e        // <--- LOCATION OF THE .dll FILE
outfile=-o main.exe

all : main.o fileReader.o main

clean :
    del *.o *.exe

main: main.o fileReader.o numbers.o
    $(compiler) main.o $(standLib) $(include) $(ExtLibrary) $(outfile)

main.o : main.cpp fileReader.cpp
    $(compiler) -c main.cpp $(standLib) $(include) $(ExtLibrary) 

fileReader.o : fileReader.cpp fileReader.h
    $(compiler) -c fileReader.cpp $(standLib) 

numbers.o : numbers.cpp numbers.h
    $(compiler) -c numbers.cpp $(standlib)
```

**What am i missing ? Thanks for any input or help !**

** UPDATE  **

i found that i can execute my program fine as long as its running in the same directory as openssl where the libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll is located.

How can i build my program so that it can run it on its own without openssl installed on the computer ? IE: if i want to give it to a friend who doesnt have openssl installed on his machine.

Comment: Add that directory to your system path, or copy the dll to the same directory as your executable.

Comment: yes sorry i found that i can in fact execute my program as long as im in the openssl directory....is there a way to compile in those library's so that my .exe can run on its own ? (not needing openssl installed on the computer + being in the same directory as my .dll)

Comment: Yes, that's called static linking. How to do it depends your tool chain, it's pretty easy to search for.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue you should just add openssl's `/bin` directory to your path (using environment variables).

Answer (score -2):

1. Uninstall & Reinstall mosquitto
2. copy both libcrypto.dll & libssl.dll files into mosquitto directory and reinstall mosquitto
3. Run mosquitto in cmd prompt:

   `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto`
   `mosquitto`
4. Execute this sub command: `mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -t "#" -v`
5. You should see messages coming from `mosquitto.org` test server

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the problem?